# How do I use a function to CALL another function?

Tags: python, function

I have this code that works when it's not in the function form, but doesn't when it is one.

I am able to call `grade()`, but get an error when `award()` is added.

Here is what I have so far

```
def award(firstplace, secondplace):
    print("")#return       
    print("The Player of the Year is: " + firstplace)
    print("The Runner Up is: " + secondplace)

def grade():
    count = 0
    playeroftheyear = 0
    runnerup = 0
    firstplace = (" ")
    secondplace = (" ")

for results in range (0,5):
    name = input("Player Name: ")
    fieldgoal = input("FG%: ")
    fieldgoal = int(fieldgoal)

    if fieldgoal > playeroftheyear:
        runnerup = playeroftheyear
        secondplace = firstplace
        playeroftheyear = fieldgoal
        firstplace = name

    elif fieldgoal > runnerup:
        runnerup = fieldgoal
        secondplace = name

award(firstplace, secondplace)
return

grade()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXX/Downloads/demo (1).py", line 41, in <module>
    grade()
  File "/Users/XXX/Downloads/demo (1).py", line 38, in grade
    award()
s  File "/Users/XX/Downloads/demo (1).py", line 14, in award
    print("The Player of the Year is: " + firstplace)
fNameError: global name 'firstplace' is not defined

Comment: think you want raw_input() instead of input(), because you want name to be a string from the user. input() calls eval(raw_input(prompt)). Also some indentation errors in original code.

Comment: It seems the original poster is using Python 3, in which `input()` is equivalent to Python 2.x `raw_input()`.

Comment: Yes I am using python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `firstplace`, like `secondplace` exists only in `grade`, but not in `award`. Hence, when you try to access it from `award`, you get the error.

You need to pass `secondplace` and `firstplace` as a parameter:

```
def award(firstplace, secondplace):
    print("")     
    print("The Player of the Year is: " + firstplace)
    print("The Runner Up is: " + secondplace)

def grade():
    ...
    award(firstplace, secondplace)
    return

grade()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stuck on it for awhile.

Comment: Okay, I will. It says I have to wait a few minutes before I can.

Comment: Can you help me edit my program so that it will include third place? Thanks!!

Comment: my program only includes first and second place (player of the year and runner up) 

i want to be able to add a third place too!!

Comment: If you want your program to work better, you can put the names and fieldgoals in a list of tuples, like `[('Player1', 30), ('Player2', 15)]`. Then, you can sort it using the `sorted` function: `sorted(data_list, key=lambda t: t[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions set up a new namespace.  names that you define *inside* a function can't be used *outside* the function unless you explicitly say they can be with the `global` keyword.

In this case, you're defining names inside of `grade` (`firstplace`, `secondplace`, etc.), but those names are not available to `award` because they only live inside the `grade` function.  To let them out, you could add:

```
global firstplace
global secondplace
```

at the top of your `grade` function.  However, **that's definitely not the best approach.**  The best approach would be to pass them as arguments:

```
def award(firstplace, secondplace):
   ...
```

And then you call `award` like so:

```
award(firstplace, secondplace)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of you guys have the same answer, who would you want me to give the "answered" to?